# My Chinese Story, need correction, any suggestion?

Tags: simplified-characters, learning, writing-critique

Are you guys aware of any website service or any language exchange platform where one can post their stories or essays and get them checked?

Also, below is my story, if anyone finds a very striking error, please do let me know. Of course it's not possible to go through the entire story and correct it word by word, I understand.

我一个小孩子的时候住在美国。 我是在那儿出生的。 我爸爸妈妈一些年以后座飞机来到美国的。
他们买到了一个很大的公寓。 我在那家公寓长大。 附近我有很多朋友。 我们在美国住五-六年。 然后，我们建搬家到印度。由于很大堵车，污染环境，和人口密集，印度给我留下了不太好的印象。然而什么时候以后，我开始了喜欢印度和印度的文化。 印度和美国并不一样。他们见间有很多差异。
我岁十一年龄以后，我们再搬家回到美国。这次我根本不喜欢美国。 当我终于适应印度的周围我父母宣布了我们要回去美国。原因才是他们都不喜欢印度有点儿。
现在我们还住在华盛顿，美国。我喜欢在这儿。但是我很想印度。有一天我一定要搬家去印度。

-美理
2016.07.12

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this website doesn't provide a proofreading service, [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com) is a more suitable place to go :)

Comment: You born in US.  Then some years later your dad and mom came to US by freight.  .....   very very striking .....

Comment: @HenryHO I guess that was 以前 instead of 以后

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this website is not a proofreading service, and the OP has not stated what they believe to be potential issues with their piece.

Comment: 我小时候住在美国。我是在那儿出生的。我的爸爸妈妈是几年以后坐飞机来到美国的。他们买了一个很大的公寓。我在那个公寓长大。我的周围有很多朋友。我们在美国住了五、六年。然后，我们搬家到了印度。由于堵车严重、环境污染和人口密集，印度给我留下了不太好的印象。然而不知从什么时候开始，我喜欢上了印度和印度的文化。印度和美国并不一样，他们之间有很多差异。在我十一岁的时候，我们再次搬家回到了美国。这次我根本不喜欢美国。当我终于适应了印度以后我的父母宣布我们要回美国去。原因是他们都有点儿不喜欢印度。现在我们还住在美国华盛顿。我喜欢这儿。但是我很想印度。有一天我一定要搬家去印度。

Comment: Haha! Thank you very much. I posted on lang-8 and got a very nice response. And thank you @songyuanyao . Your corrections are very helpful. Especially where you've used 周围 replacing the 附近。Thank you Henry HO for pointing out the most striking bit here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't use too much period, only when you finish saying a short piece of contents. In general your Chinese is good, you know a lot Chinese words. (My English is not good enough, not sure you understand all of my saying)
我还是一个小孩子的时候住在美国。 我是在那儿出生的， 我爸爸妈妈几年后坐飞机来到美国， 他们买到了一个很大的公寓， 我在那家公寓长大， 附近有很多我的朋友。 我们在美国住五六年，然后，我们搬家到印度，由于很大堵车，环境污染，和人口密集，印度给我留下了不太好的印象，然而不知道什么时候开始，我喜欢印度和印度的文化。 印度和美国并不一样，他们之间有很多差异。 我十一岁以后，我们再搬家回美国。这次我根本不喜欢美国，当我终于适应印度的环境的时候我父母宣布了我们要回美国，原因是他们都有点儿不喜欢印度。 现在我们还住在美国华盛顿，我喜欢在这儿，但是我很想印度，有一天我一定要搬家去印度。